# Basic dashboard to manage posts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, dashboard

I have a blog that use devise for authentication and where user can create posts, I have created a basic dashboard where users will be able to manage their posts

this is my dashboard controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
def index
 @posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => [ "user_id = ?", @current_user ]) 
end
```

this my dashboard view

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> 
 <%= post.content %> 
<% end %>
```

this my user model

```
has_many :posts
```

and my post model

```
belongs_to :user
```

this is my schema.rb

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

but when i go to the dashboard i am not getting any of my post and when i change my dashboard controller to

```
def index
 @posts = Post.all
end
```

I'am getting all the posts so can someone tell me where is my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find(:all, :conditions => [])` was deprecated in Rails 3.2. Instead try:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.where(:user_id => current_user)
end
```

Also, make sure you are adding a user_id in the create method in your controller:

```
def create
  @post = post.new(post_params)
  @post.user_id = current_user

  REST OF CODE GOES HERE
end
```

Comment: whit this code I'm getting all post but i want just to get my own post

Comment: Are you sure you have a user_id column in your posts table?

Comment: I have not understand your question can you please specify more

Comment: yes i have just add a few hours ago a user_id:integer to my posts table

Comment: On your dashboard view page (where you have the code `<% @posts.each`, can you put the code `<%= @posts %>` somewhere and show us the format of @posts? It'd be helpful to see

Comment: so in place  <%= post.content %>  i have put <%= @posts %> but i haven't get anything

Comment: Don't place it in the loop. Place it before the `<% @posts.each`

Comment: also don't get anything, can this problem is due to my posts create controller?

Comment: It's not very likely. What does your db/schema.rb look like?

Comment: this is my schema.rb   create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

Comment: If you try and create a post, what happens?

Comment: the post will be created

Comment: Is it created with a user id? Make sure in your create action you have something like `@post.user_id = @current_user` before you save it

Comment: this is my create controller how can i change it def create
    @post = post.new(post_params)

    if params[:preview_button] || !@post.save
      render :action => 'new'
    else
      flash[:notice] = "votre article à été crée "
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
  end

Comment: I have changed my create controller to @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params) but nothing happen

Comment: @user3304070, try keeping your original code and placing `@post.user_id = @current_user` directly underneath `@post = post.new(post_params)`

Comment: thank you very much i appreciate your help it work but you must change the @current_user in the create to current_user. Thank you very much

Comment: It work just for the 2 latest posts created now when i created a new post i don't find it in my dashboard view do you have a idea why

Comment: Do you mean the posts you created before you made the change to the create method? Those won't show up because they weren't saved with a user_id

Comment: i have change current_user to current_user.id in booth index and create actions and it work now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`@posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => [ "user_id = ?", @current_user ])`

with

`@posts = @current_user.posts`

Comment: I am gettin this error undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass  and when i have try this @posts = current_user.posts i'm not getting any post in the view

Comment: No i haven't forget it, however thank you for your help